# Discord.js, dming people with a certain role

Tags: javascript, discord.js

currently creating a bot using discord.js that uses a cron-job to dm people a certain message regularly. The cron-job code itself works, I tried by logging. The problem in my code is when I try to actually dm people using the code, it doesn't work. I have looked around and still have no idea how to do this, I'v tried recycling some code I found on here which didn't work.

```
message.guild.roles.cache.get('[ROLE-ID]').members.array.forEach(member =>
{
    message.member.send('[MESSAGE]').catch.console.error();;
});;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're misusing a *lot* of functions/properties in this code. Make sure to always look at the discord.js docs to see how to use some of the methods.

First of all, [`Collection#array()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=array) is a function. Second of all, you don't actually need `Collection#array()` because [`Collection#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach) already exists with the same exact* functionality.

<sub>*for your use case</sub>

Third of all, even though you're using `member` as a parameter in the `forEach()` function, you're still using `message.member` in the code. This will just send the same message to the message author per the number of people in that role.

Fourth of all, [`Promise#catch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch) is a function and `console.error()` should go *inside* of it, not be attached as a property.

Guides to understand promises:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises
- https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/async-await.html
- https://javascript.info/async-await

Finally, mass dming people is a very bad idea unless there are minimal users using that role. Discord can easily ban your bot, as it's against the TOS (again, it depends on the amount of people0.